# How to split an array in fortran?

Tags: fortran

I have made a 10x10 array with random values. 
Using fortran 90.

**Edit:** I found a solution to my problem, going to add it when it is in a more presentable state.

```
      real :: x
      integer, dimension(10,10) :: matrix
      integer d,f,j,sum

      do d=1,10
          do f=1,10
              call RANDOM_NUMBER(x)
              j = FLOOR(10*x)  
              matrix(d,f) = j
              sum= sum + j
              write(*,*)'RND number', matrix(d,f)
          end do
      end do
      write(*,*)'Sum of all elements in the array: ', sum
```

Now, what I want to do is - to create 2 new arrays called array1 and array2, they would both be 5x10, and contain columns 1-5, and 6-10 of the initial array.

This problem I have is one step in a larger assignment, which involves sending the new arrays to slave nodes (using MPI), doing some work with them, and sending results back to the master node. But that is out of scope for this question.

Comment: I am not in the mood to do your homework for you unless You take the time to show some example where you try to split the array apart and are stuck.

Comment: I decided against that because none of my approaches compiled. And I felt I would get ripped to shreds by Fortran veterans.

I've come up with a simple solution, I use array dimensions as parameters, and simply loop through all elements in first 5 columns, and then the last 5 columns. I thought I needed to create separate arrays, but actually I don't.

I will post an answer when my solution is a bit more polished.

Comment: *"I decided against that because none of my approaches compiled. And I felt I would get ripped to shreds by Fortran veterans. "* We come here, because we want to help people with their code, really. We just don't want to write their code for them. If you just want to avoid unsolicited advices about your coding style (which I tend to give), you can just say that.

Comment: Also note that you've forgotten to set sum to 0 before the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time post up what you did...

```
 integer, dimension(10,10) :: matrix
 integer, dimension(10, 5) :: trunk
 integer, dimension(10, 5) :: tail

 ...
 trunk = matrix(:, 1: 5)
 tail  = matrix(:, 6:10)
```

Or... maybe EQUIVALENCE could work, which you would have to try as I may have it wrong...

```
EQUIVALENCE (Matrix,Trunk), (Tail,Matrix(6,1))
```

@Vladimir said, 'If you just want to avoid unsolicited advices about your coding style (which I tend to give), you can just say that.' and I may do the same.

SUM is definitely either a PURE or PURE ELEMENTAL intrinsic.
I am not sure about RANDOM_NUMBER...
But this may be more stylish as you can omit the loops:

```
Matrix = RANDOM_NUMBER(x) 
WHERE (Matrix <= <somefloor>)...
mySum = SUM(Matrix)
```

Comment: I'm not sure `equivalence` is ever a good solution to a Fortran coding issue these days.  I'm quite sure it's not a good solution for this question.